# How do I express "if object intersects 'any object in this array' then..."

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

Been trying to work on a simple game while learning Xcode and Objective-C.

I'm trying to get an object which falls from the top of the screen to land on a platform. There are multiple platforms which are all UIImageViews.

I want to use an array for the platforms which the object could land on, rather than typing out if statements for each platform. I've looked around at other people's questions and am trying ideas based on what they had. Here's what I have so far within my game loop:

```
CGRect platformFrame = [(UIView *)[platformArray objectAtIndex:i] frame];
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(object.frame, platformFrame)) {
    objectVelocity.y += gravity.y;
    objectVelocity.x = 0;
}
```

This is what I have in my 'viewDidLoad' to add the objects to the array:

```
platformArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[platformArray addObject:platform1];  
[platformArray addObject:platform2];
[platformArray addObject:platform3];
```

At the moment this returns an error: "Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGARBT"."

I've read that this is a result of using NSMutableArray.

Currently I can't tell if my code will work or not, due to the error. So I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it, or a way around the SIGARBT error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** Thanks for the quick reply! Hopefully that will work but unfortunately I'm still getting the SIGARBT error so I can't see the result.

As for more details on this error, it appears when I try to run the app, although it states 'no issues' until that point.

The error appears in the main.m here:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

The error appears on the line starting 'return'

I read that using an NSMutableArray can cause this.

"Values returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable, even if you set a mutable object as the value."

So I'm not sure how to work around it.

Comment: Sorry didn't realise this wasn't an xcode specific question. I thought the error it was returning might have been due to the way xcode sets up files and works.

Comment: It's ok :) That's why we can edit stuff for other people.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that check with every object in your `platformArray` array, you can just use the code you have now inside a `for` loop with some minor modification:

```
for(UIView * platform in platformArray) {
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(object.frame, platform.frame)) {
        // Collision
        objectVelocity.y += gravity.y;
        objectVelocity.x = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you can be more specific about the `SIGABRT` you receive (are there any other messages?), we can be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've updated my question with more details.